# Disable Power Button Emergency Call

Tags: android, android-13

Is there a way to disable the emergency call functionality of the power button programatically on Android 13? I checked the DevicePolicyManager class (my app is a device owner) but could not find anything.

Comment: This probably isn't legal in most of the world.  Removing the ability to call emergency services is a horrible idea for a phone.  If this is for a kiosk like device for a business, you may want to look at a custom OS image that does so.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you for your reply. yes my application is indeed a kiosk mode app. I feel like that if my App is device owner, Android should allow me to disable this functionality as the device is not used as a "standard" cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to disable the automatically initiated emergency call after touching the power button 5 times. (Tested on an Samsung Galaxy S20 FE updated to Android version 13.)

`Settings->Safety and emergency->Emergency SOS: disable`

Important:
This does NOT disable the feature to call emergency services on a locked phone, it only disables that emergency services get called automatically by just pushing the power button multiple times.

Note:
This was added as a safety feature with a new Android update. While it is very good that the emergency services can be called any time even with a locked phone, (Which is still possible after disabling the automatic power button call.), it is not good to enable this new "feature" by default with an OS update. I found this out the hard way over the last two weeks as the emergency services got called 2 times unintentionally on my phone. This is bad as the important hotline get blocked with unintentionally calls only initiated by pushing the power button of the phone.

Comment: thanks for your detailed comment. Yes, i also realized that between android 12 and 13 the functionality was changed from opt-in to opt-out. My application is a Kiosk-mode application and I do not allow my users to go into the settings menu. I would need a way to disable this feature through code, but I think Android does not provide this ability yet.